# Cannot Figure out the syntax error in this formula shows Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula

```
AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Customer_Support',
    OR(
        ISCHANGED( Type ),
        ISCHANGED( CaseSubType__c ),
        ISNEW()
    ),
    TEXT(Type) = 'Collections',
    OR(
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'General Collections Inquiries and Updates',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Invoice Copies Request',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Collections Dispute',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Refund Request',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Statement of Account',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Bankruptcy Notice',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Payment Plan Request'
    )
    Account.BillingCountry = 'Canada'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always write formula on a text editor and indent it. A comma is missing before `Account.BillingCountry = 'Canada'`:

```
AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Customer_Support',
    OR(
        ISCHANGED( Type ),
        ISCHANGED( CaseSubType__c ),
        ISNEW()
    ),
    TEXT(Type) = 'Collections',
    OR(
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'General Collections Inquiries and Updates',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Invoice Copies Request',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Collections Dispute',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Refund Request',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Statement of Account',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Bankruptcy Notice',
        TEXT(CaseSubType__c) = 'Payment Plan Request'
    ),
    Account.BillingCountry = 'Canada'
)
```

By the way, to know whether a picklist fields (i.e. `Case.Type`) holds a specific value there is [`ISPICKVAL(picklist_field, text_value)`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_ispickval.htm&type=5) function, which returns a returns true if the value of `picklist_field` matches `text_value`. While `TEXT(picklist_field)` converts a picklist value to a Text value in the master language of your organization, not the language of the current user.